# Normal n-dimensional Distribution in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

Are there any functions or algorithms in C# to get n-dimensional vector whis has normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw `n` independent 1D normal variables, the latter problem being left as a googling exercise.